# Cannot install proj 7.2.0

Tags: apt-get, proj, pyproj

I am on Ubuntu 19.10 and I am trying to install proj 7.2.0

[According to the website](https://proj.org/install.html) I should use this:

```
sudo apt-get install proj-bin
```

But it seems that this command installs version 5.2.0:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libappindicator1 libdbusmenu-gtk4
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  proj-bin
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 63,9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 245 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/universe amd64 proj-bin amd64 5.2.0-1 [63,9 kB]
Fetched 63,9 kB in 0s (530 kB/s)  
Selecting previously unselected package proj-bin.
(Reading database ... 278906 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../proj-bin_5.2.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking proj-bin (5.2.0-1) ...
Setting up proj-bin (5.2.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.7-3) ...
```

Any ideas on how to install 7.2.0?

I need this version because it is the minimum supported in order to install [pyproj 3](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/installation.html):

```
pip install pyproj
```

This gives:

```
Collecting pyproj
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/17/e5/3f5cdff3e955bcd768cdb0f4236f2d6e022aaa72f57caf7f4d5f552c88fc/pyproj-3.0.0.post1.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Minimum supported proj version is 7.2.0, installed version is DeprecationWarning:. For more information see: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/installation.html
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-uiv4m209/pyproj/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/installation.html

If you install `pip>=19.0` you won't need to install PROJ, it should install the `manylinux2010` wheels.